# pass User obj to view trough custom authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class Authenticate(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        token = request.data.get('token')
        if token:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=token)
            return (user, None)
        else:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed()
```

this is my custom authentication in Django Rest Framework, I would like to pass

> user = User.objects.get(pk=token)

this user object to the view, so I may have a similar request.auth which is build in DRF

how can I pass this User obj to the view ?
and how can i catch it to the view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already get that user from `request.user` as explained by the documentation:

> The authentication schemes are always defined as a list of classes. REST framework will attempt to authenticate with each class in the list, and will set request.user and request.auth using the return value of the first class that successfully authenticates.

Comment: Yes but this is a custom authentication, and custom user auth of django, I am not using Django authentication

Comment: @gentos Yes this is a custom authentication backend to be used within Django's auth system, so as Linovia says you will get the user in the usual place, request.user.

Comment: @daniel I am not using Django autj system this is a custom based auth system.

Comment: This is a class with an `authenticate` method which returns a user. Therefore it can be used as the backend in Django's auth framework, which is the answer to your original question.

Comment: @gentos You're using at least Django REST framework authentication from which documentation my quote is taken from. I'm sorry I didn't get your question right. You may want to rephrase the question if our answers aren't what you expect.

Comment: @Linovia thank you for the answer it did solve my problem.